# How do I change the Web Service Account for SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server-2005, configuration, service, ssrs

I am trying to configure a Report Server on SQL Server 2005 and need to change the ASP.NET Web Service Account.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: I've managed to change this but still can't initialise the server due to service rights.

Answer (score 1):

The application pool identity was changed to the appropriate account in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally performed using the "Reporting Services Configuration" tool, and navigating to the Windows Service Identity page to make the change.